# calling a function within a class with a Joomla module

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a Joomla helper class that I'm using for module development with a method I'm trying to call:

```
class modCamcloudReferralHelper
{
        /*
         * Sanitize email form
         */
        public function isInjected($str) {
            $inject = "/(\r|\t|%0A|%0D|%08|%09)+/i";
            return (preg_match($inject, $str) > 0);
        }

        public static function sendEmail() {


            $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

            $email = $jinput->post->get('email', '', 'STRING');


            //check email is fine
            if (isInjected($email)){ //never get into this code and it causes some sort of failure
                echo "blah";
            }

        }
}
```

Simple, right? But this code just gives me a blank page and I don't see any errors...anywhere. I can instead just put this code right into my `sendEmail` function and it works just fine:

```
        $inject = "/(\r|\t|%0A|%0D|%08|%09)+/i";
        if (preg_match($inject, $email) > 0){
            echo "This works";
        }
```

I've had this problem with my Joomla components I've built before. For some reason calling this function from inside the same class is not working. It must be a Joomla thing...or I'm going nuts. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the method with a reference to its container, even if it's local.

So the right syntax here is:

```
if (self::isInjected($email))
```

of from another class:

```
modCamcloudReferralHelper::isInjected(
```

This is good for helpers: just make sure you declare the method you are invoking as static

```
public static function isInjected($str) {
```

If however you're calling a method on an instantiated class (a view, a template, a model, you should use

```
$this->method()
```

Comment: He needs to declare `isInjected` as static before being able to do that, you might want to add that to your answer :)